# Amending a PR and closing original

Tags: git, github, merge, commit

I've checked out a local branch of a GitHub PR as per [this description](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/). It suggested

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
```

On that local branch I've applied some fixes and want to

- merge all commits to master (both the original PR and my local ones)
- close the original PR so that it's visible that it was taken care of (and appreciated)

What would be the appropriate steps to take?

I'm considering pushing the local branch to new remote branch, create a new PR, and merge that with a "closes #`original PR`" message. Will this work? What adverse effects will it have? Can I close the original PR using a merge message, or does that have to be a commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that if your changes on this PR are more like cosmetic\small fixes, than you should:

- Checkout PR's source branch (clone the **fork** that PR's author created) `git clone https://github.com/USERNAME/REPO && cd REPO && git checkout BRANCHNAME`
- Make your changes
- Push it directly to fork repo
- Changes will appear in the original PR
- Merge original PR

So probably you don't need to create new PR for this, just amend existing one instead.

See Github page for reference https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/. Though to be able to commit into fork branch you need PR creator to put checkbox "Allow edit from maintainers".

But in other cases (i.e. if the original PR was somehow messy or was waiting for a long time and requires efforts rebasing it now; or author didn't put "Allow edits from maintainers") the approach you suggested is perfectly fine as well, there is nothing wrong in creating new PR and merging it instead of original one. In this case I'd recommend you to simply comment on original PR like "Transferred to the new PR #123, closing this one", so it's clear what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks. But as I created a local branch as instructed using `git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` I now have a local branch that is not the actual PR. What is the upstream branch for the PR, `pull/ID/head`?

Comment: According to Github [article](https://help.github.com/articles/committing-changes-to-a-pull-request-branch-created-from-a-fork/) it's required that creator of the PR put a checkbox "allow edit from maintainers" for this

Comment: That means that either I should have not created a local branch, or I should have gone with checking out for command line merge and added the fixes there, right? Now my choices seems to be redo using the merge scenario, redo on master after merge or create a new PR.

Comment: Or I could even just merge my local branch onto local master, push that, and close the PR with nice comments, right?

Comment: You have a lot of options in general, right. There is no really "wrong" solution. It all depends on the exact type and amount of changes.
But please note that rebasing of someone else's commits will invalidate its signature (if any). If you want to keep properly signed commits you need to do your changes on top of original PR without changing other person's commits. Of course, it may not be the case for some small project, but in general people may care about it.

Comment: I ended up doing the standard command line version of merging a PR (the one you get as "command line instructions" next to your merge-button in github) and then adding my changes before pushing. That turned out nice. With that approach I also got a merge-commit that I could use to comment on the extra commits as well as closing the PR.